# "Body not assignable to class" using ActiveMQ Artemis & Spring Boot

Tags: java, jms, deserialization, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I'm starting with Artemis and JMS, and I have problem to get message back.
The producer correctly ask to the message; which is get and reply correctly. The problem is in the final phase, to get the data.

I tried to specify the type, but without success:

```
resp.setJMSType("com.nesdl.flyaway.core.modelmessages.ApplicationsEvent");
log.debug(resp.getJMSType() + " / " + resp.getBody(String.class));
ApplicationsEvent response = resp.getBody(ApplicationsEvent.class);
```

I get this stacktrace:

```
2021-06-02 09:39:40.060 DEBUG 14288 --- [p-nio-80-exec-1] c.n.f.f.s.ApplicationsServicesImpl       : com.nesdl.flyaway.core.modelmessages.ApplicationsEvent / is null : "{\"applicationsDto\":[{\"id\":1,\"version\":0,\"dateCreated\":\"2021-05-18T17:52:30+0000\",\"dateLastModified\":\"2021-05-18T17:52:30+0000\",\"uuid\":\"66ef5e19-e5ac-48d1-86c8-85d26e0fa205\",\"valid\":true,\"modified\":false,\"toHistorize\":false,\"name\":\"TestApp\",\"description\":\"Première application\"}]}"
2021-06-02 09:39:40.066 DEBUG 14288 --- [p-nio-80-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: javax.jms.MessageFormatException: Body not assignable to class com.nesdl.flyaway.core.modelmessages.ApplicationsEvent
2021-06-02 09:39:40.071 ERROR 14288 --- [p-nio-80-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.jms.MessageFormatException: Body not assignable to class com.nesdl.flyaway.core.modelmessages.ApplicationsEvent] with root cause

javax.jms.MessageFormatException: Body not assignable to class com.nesdl.flyaway.core.modelmessages.ApplicationsEvent
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessage.getBody(ActiveMQMessage.java:740) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.15.0.jar:2.15.0]
    at com.nesdl.flyaway.front.services.ApplicationsServicesImpl.getApplications(ApplicationsServicesImpl.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.nesdl.flyaway.front.services.ApplicationsServicesImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$293cab08.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
```

etc.

So, the message back content the good Data, but unable to assign to a specific class.

My producer

```java
@Override
public List<ApplicationDto> getApplications() throws IOException, JMSException {
    ApplicationsEvent mess = ApplicationsEvent.builder()
            .applicationsDto(new ArrayList<>())
            .build();
    log.debug("message sent :"+mess.toString());
    Message resp = jmsTemplate.sendAndReceive(JmsSystemConfig.APPLICATIONS_QUEUE, new MessageCreator() {
        @SneakyThrows
        @Override
        public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            Message appMess = session.createTextMessage(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mess));
            appMess.setStringProperty("_type","com.nesdl.flyaway.core.modelmessages.ApplicationsEvent");
            return appMess;
        }
    });
    resp.setJMSType("com.nesdl.flyaway.core.modelmessages.ApplicationsEvent");
    log.debug(resp.getJMSType() + " / " + resp.getBody(String.class));
    ApplicationsEvent response = resp.getBody(ApplicationsEvent.class);
    log.debug(response.getApplicationsDto().toString());
    return response.getApplicationsDto();
}
```

My consumer

```java
@JmsListener(destination = JmsSystemConfig.APPLICATIONS_QUEUE)
public void replyApplications(@Payload ApplicationsEvent appsEvent, @Headers MessageHeaders headers, Message message) throws JMSException, JsonProcessingException {
    ApplicationsEvent resp = ApplicationsEvent.builder()
            .applicationsDto(as.getApplications())
            .build();
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(message.getJMSReplyTo(),objectMapper.writeValueAsString(resp));
    log.debug("reply ok "+resp.toString()+" / "+objectMapper.writeValueAsString(resp));
}
```

And The JMS Config

```java
@Configuration
public class JmsConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        return converter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem here is that you're sending a *text* message, but you're trying to assign it directly to a `com.nesdl.flyaway.core.modelmessages.ApplicationsEvent` object using [`javax.jms.Message.getBody()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getBody-java.lang.Class-) which just won't work. You must convert the text to this object just like you convert this object to text using `objectMapper.writeValueAsString`, e.g.:

```java
ApplicationsEvent response = objectMapper.readValue(resp.getBody(String.class), ApplicationsEvent.class);
```

Also, there's no reason to call `javax.jms.Message.setJMSType()` here. It essentially does nothing so you're safe to just remove it.

Comment: It's exactly that. Thanks to correct my post and solve my problem !

Answer (score -1):

it says you are **trying to assign or add a JMS message body INTO an "event class"**.
Events usually have a named overridden method for code to be placed inside to run that code if the event is triggered.

It may be this here , the compiler error message seems to indicate "resp" , a message body and "response" ApplicationsEvent.

```
resp.setJMSType("com.nesdl.flyaway.core.modelmessages.ApplicationsEvent");
        log.debug(resp.getJMSType() + " / " + resp.getBody(String.class));
        ApplicationsEvent response = resp.getBody(ApplicationsEvent.class);
        log.debug(response.getApplicationsDto().toString());
```